# How to handle " in Regex Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to grab `fary_trigger_post` in the code below using Regex. However, I don't understand why it always includes `"` in the end of the matched pattern, which I don't expect.
Any idea or suggestion?

```
re.match(
r'-instance[ "\']*(.+)[ "\']*$', 
'-instance "fary_trigger_post" '.strip(), 
flags=re.S).group(1)


'fary_trigger_post"'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try: `r'''-instance[ "']*([^"]*)[ "']*$'''`

Comment: `.` matches a quotation mark, as well as any other character (except line terminators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (`.+`) is greedy and grabs ANY character until the end of the input.  If you modified your input to include characters after the final double quote (e.g. `'-instance "fary_trigger_post" asdf'`) you would find the double quote and the remaining characters in the output (e.g. `fary_trigger_post" asdf`).  Instead of `.+` you should try `[^"\']+` to capture all characters except the quotes.  This should return what you expect.

`re.match(r'-instance[ "\']*([^"\']+)[ "\'].*$', '-instance "fary_trigger_post" '.strip(), flags=re.S).group(1)`

Also, note that I modified the end of the expression to use `.*` which will match any characters following the last quote.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd use in your matching string, but it's hard to provide a better answer without knowing all your cases:

```
r'-instance\s+"(.+)"\s*$'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to get group 1 (i.e. `(.+)`) regex will follow this match to the end of string, as it can match `.` (any character) 1 or more times (but it will take maximum amount of times). I would suggest use the following pattern:

```
'-instance[ "\']*(.+)["\']+ *$'
```

This will require regex to match all spaces in the end and all quoutes separatelly, so that it won't be included into group 1